# May a linking verb be omitted in a sentence with compound subject?

Tags: compound-subjects, linking-verbs

Consider the sentence:

> Our son, John, is 15 and our daughter, Mary, 11.

Is it grammatical? I have read such omission of the linking verb (especially *is*) in a sentence with a compound subject. I wanted to know if the linking verb attaches to both the subjects. Is the above preferred to the more straightforward (and grammatical) construction:

> Our son, John, is 15 and our daughter, Mary, is 11.

?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I think the downvoter probably wanted you to ask your question on English Language Learners.

Comment: I see. I think we are _all_ learning this great language, aren't we? And one were to go by answers to this question, it hardly feels like a question not appropriate for this SE.

Comment: And why use -1 to indicate a probable move to another SE? Is that what meta SE asks us to do? If true, that's quite unfortunate, @DecapitatedSoul! (I know you are just helping and you are not the downvoter; but this makes me sad :-( ).

Comment: I've counteracted the downvote. Downvotes just mean that someone disagrees with your question.

Comment: Casting a _bare_ downvote (the one without any justification) is easy, just click on the arrow! That ease, I believe, makes people -- even seasoned SEers -- sloppy. It also promotes speculation among others. Some people take it personally (like what I may be perceived as doing here). Maybe SE should abandon casting bare downvotes. If, on the other hand,  _any_ justification is provided, the downvote could be accepted. I know, all of this might be already discussed somewhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Our son, John, **is** 15 and our daughter, Mary, __ 11.*

Yes: it's grammatical.

This is called 'gapped coordination' (or 'gapping'), which occurs when the middle part of a non-initial coordinate is omitted but recoverable from the corresponding part of the first coordinate.

The gap marked __ is understood by reference to the first coordinate, in this case "is".

I prefer the version without gapping, especially in speech, but usage varies.

Edit: Here's a link to Wiki's article on gapping [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping)